# Powershell Script Login via ssh and send a return

Tags: powershell, ssh, automation

I have the challenge to automate a ssh login to a Linux box which asks after login th accept a eula. So I need to press two time the arrow down key and after this the a key and a enter. Is there a way to do this with power shell?

Comment: You forgot to post your ocde. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with SendKeys.

Start the process that way we can find the window easier. Otherwise, just change the console title and search for that instead.

```
Start-Process ssh Server-Name
Sleep 1
```

To send keys to a window you need to activate that window "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" was the title of my window once I did a Start-Process

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe')
```

Then your config.

```
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('{DOWN}')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('{DOWN}')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('a')
```

Login

```
$wshell.SendKeys('mysupersecurepasswordnobodywilleverguess')
$wshell.SendKeys('{ENTER}')
```

I will suggest you encrypt your password before using it in a script like this.